# How can I calculate the real Ethers from the API of etherscan

Tags: etherscan, balances, external-api

Having this address:
https://etherscan.io/address/0x7cB57B5A97eAbe94205C07890BE4c1aD31E486A8

The balance on the web is **21.76252288478066826** Ether

But using the API the balance is:
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/api?apikey=GY9KKYEJF1HDEPIAIRGA66R2RIQWQXV9UZ&module=account&action=balance&address=0x7cB57B5A97eAbe94205C07890BE4c1aD31E486A8&tag=latest

**5000014636180791194320764**

I don't even know what unit is that. Because the documentation don't say anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking at two different networks. The first is on Mainnet, the second is on Ropsten (test network).

If you query the account via the Mainnet API, https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=balance&address=0x7cB57B5A97eAbe94205C07890BE4c1aD31E486A8&tag=latest then you get

`{"status":"1","message":"OK","result":"21767542884780668260"}`

Units are Wei = 10^-18 Ether. So this is 21.767542884780668260 Eth.